# Eclipse Content Assist shows two same prompt,how to solve this?

Tags: android, eclipse, content-assist

It's so strange, I never meet this before. Like this, all the prompt are double! How can i solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a Clean Project under Project > Clean...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Advanced. Make sure you don't have e.g. both "Java Non-Type Proposals" and "Java Proposals" checked.

Comment: Thanks,I will try this when I go back home.